# visual studio font style by text value

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have a lot of logging statements in my code. While these make for good debug information, they make the code harder to read. Since they all start with

```
CommonLogger.LogMessage(...)
```

is there any way that Visual Studio (or Resharper) can automatically display these in a light grey font so that the eye passes over them when I'm trying to read the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper can't do this.

If you are still keen to get this feature you may want to write your own Visual Studio Extension. Consider the extension [ItalicComments](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0b439a8a-e21a-4e26-b82b-054fbf0acab7/) written by Noah Richards (who contributes on Stack Overflow)

This extension not only provides comments in italics but also "XML doc comment tags are made slightly smaller and partially transparent, so they fade into the background a bit more."

Download his source and check out the `Fade` method in `ViewCreationListener`

Note, to open his project you need the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en) installed